# Take three values from <SELECT> tags and join them together in SQL "DATE"?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I've been working on designing a MediaWiki extension that asks users for their date of birth, then stores that in the user database. So far I've managed to get this working via input box (If the user enters it like "2007-04-06"). As you can tell, that's terribly inefficient.

So - This data is stored as a "DATE" type (Named user_birthdate) in the SQL database, which requires the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Rather than have the user have to type this data out manually, I'd rather have a drop-down list with preset values like so:

```
<select name="birthdate-year" id="birthdate-year">
 <option value="2005">2005</option>
 <option value="2006">2006</option>
 <option value="2007">2007</option>
</select>

<select name="birthdate-month" id="birthdate-month">
 <option value="01">January</option>
 <option value="02">February</option>
 <option value="03">March</option>
</select>

<select name="birthdate-day" id="birthdate-day">
 <option value="01">1</option>
 <option value="02">2</option>
 <option value="03">3</option>
</select>
```

My issue here is that I've worked *exclusively* with JavaScript and HTML5 up to this point, I've simply never touched PHP. Here's what I'd like to know:

How do I string these options together as one value, so that the data is sent in the proper format? Like if the user selects "1997", "04" and "03", I'd want that to become one whole value which is "1997-04-03".

Answer (score 0):

Having three select lists would make the task even more time consuming for the end user than a single box, and you would still have to validate the input (i.e. to avoid things like Feb 31).

Why not have some sort of date picker or calendar that would do most of the work for you?

For examples on how this may be done, try [here](http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php).

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
<?php

// get values from post
$birthdate-year = $_POST["birthdate-year"];
$birthdate-month= $_POST["birthdate-month"];
$birthdate-day= $_POST["birthdate-day"];

// make string from values
$goodDate = $birthdate-year."-".$birthdate-month."-".$birthdate-day;
echo $goodDate; 

// or make object datetime from values 
$goodDate2 = new DateTime();
$goodDate2->setDate($birthdate-year, $birthdate-month, $birthdate-day);
echo $goodDate2->format('Y-m-d'); 

?>
```

javaScript:

```
<script>
var year = document.getElementById(birthdate-year).value;
var month = document.getElementById(birthdate-month).value;
var day = document.getElementById(birthdate-day).value;

var goodDate = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;

alert(goodDate);
</script>
```